# Lock Statement C#

Tags: c#, locking

Say I have three threads that need access to a collection and I use a lock block around the access in each thread.  The following happens...

(1)  Thread 1 gets the lock on the collection
(2)  Thread 2 gets blocked
(3)  Thread 3 gets blocked

When Thread 1 releases the lock, who gets to take the lock next?  Is it FIFO access?

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should not care who gets the lock next.

Comment: You might extend that to say you *cannot* care.  Maybe.

Comment: I realize that I should program the threads so that I don't care, I'm just wondering what the mechanism is.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740(VS.71).aspx#vcwlkthreadingtutorialexample4mutex

"The speed and operating system of the machine running the sample can affect the output order."

Answer (score 5):

Your question implies that you are looking for a FIFO behaviour? Then you might want to try this code by Jakub Sloup:

**[Monitor/lock which remember order in C# to simulate FIFO](http://www.jakubsloup.cz/Blog/March-2009/Monitor-lock-which-remember-order-in-C--to-simulat.aspx)**

As already mentioned in the other answers there is no guaranteed order waiting threads will receive a lock.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming it's like Win32 then the answer is that it might be FIFO but it might not (it be something else). For example, a higher-priority thread should be first; but threads can get a temporary boost or drop in their priority depending on what they've been doing recently.

Comment: From what I have read, this is correct.  Lock can be thought of FIFO, but it is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 4):

As an answer to your question, all threads recieve the monitor.pulse which will then fight over who gets the lock next.

I believe that the people at wintellect wrote a blog regarding how this behaviour could lead to an unfair situation, but there is no fairness at all in the monitor.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is by definition, indeterminate.